# Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, php7

After upgrading my php automatically upgraded to php7.but [phpinfo();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neVwo.png) shows no value on PDO section. and P.S pdo is showing

```
Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 updates automatically you php to php7 version , you are just missing php7-pdo extension `sudo apt-get install php7-pdo` then restart your web server should fix your issues.

Comment: it says unable to locate php7-pdo